# Russian and Spanish babel

Tags: babel, spanish, russian

I want to use both Russian and Spanish in my document but it's not working. It just shows question marks for the Russian. Could you point out my error?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,12pt]{extbook}
\usepackage[spanish, russian]{babel} 
\selectlanguage{spanish}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}


\foreignlanguage{russian}{Смирнова, В И. (2008). ЛЕОНАРД ЭЙЛЕР: К 300-ЛЕТИЮ СО ДНЯ РОЖДЕНИЯ. Санкт-Петербург: Нестор-История.}
```

Comment: Just a guess: `latin1` is, well, for the Latin script.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that the `latin1` encoding does not cover Russian letters.  It would be best to switch to `utf8`; make sure you save you file with this encoding.

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,openany,12pt]{extbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=spanish,russian]{babel}

\begin{document}

\foreignlanguage{russian}{Смирнова, В И. (2008). ЛЕОНАРД ЭЙЛЕР: К
300-ЛЕТИЮ СО ДНЯ РОЖДЕНИЯ. Санкт-Петербург: Нестор-История.} 

\end{document}
```

With the newest version of LaTeX, utf8 will be assumed automatically and you can omit the `inputenc` package.  If you use `inputenc` is should come before the `babel` package.

The babel options allow one to specify one language as the principal one by giving `main=`.